# Disable start up prompt in Matlab in Command Window?

Tags: matlab, window, command, startup, prompt

I have recently bought the Matlab student edition for my Mac. I've installed it on my computer and now, every time I start up Matlab, I get this prompt:

Student License -- for use in conjunction with courses offered at a 
  degree-granting institution.  Professional and commercial use prohibited.

I find it a bit annoying and was wondering if there was any way to prevent it from showing at start up?

Answer (score 3):

try to start matlab using the following command:

```
matlab -nosplash
```

To controll what happens when matlab starts up you can use\edit [matlabrc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabrc.html) or use\edit [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html)  with `clc`, see more info in their documentations in the links.

Comment: That would disable the picture that precedes opening matlab, but I'm looking to do something a bit different. I'm referring to when the command window, workspace, command history, etc are open. In the command window, that student license bit appears and I can get rid of it using clc, but I would prefer not do that every time I open up Matlab.